# Bootstrap on IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

We have some machines which are still running IE 9 and we cannot install newer version of IE because of compatibility issues with some old softwares.

I have built an asp.net web app which is using Bootstrap css.

To make it compatible with IE9 browser, I have put

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

However, this is causing some of the javascript functions not to function properly. Unfortunately, console in Developer tools is empty and so I am not able to figure out the real problem.

The web app works absolutely fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Please let me know if someone has faced similar problem and a resolution.

Thank you

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using and what are the JS functions which are not working?

Comment: Wouldn't `IE=EmulateIE9` just tell newer IE's to render as IE9? If people are actually running IE9 why would you need to emulate IE9 on IE9? I may be confused...

Comment: Did you follow the pattern as in the basic template: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to include shiv's for html5 and respond.js in your html. 
download the following and save locally. 
[html5Shiv.js](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv)
[respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)
Then in your html you'll want to add the following after your CSS imports. "update the src path to where you save your files to"

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="/js/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```